# Total LBA written grows fast

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, smart

**OS:** Ubuntu 16.04

**HDD:** Samsung SSD 750 EVO 250GB

i am web developer. my desktop (2 years old) works 24/7. 
i have noticed big numbers of "Total LBAs Written" in SMART-statistics. tried to identify what is the reason but can't.

interested smartctl statistics:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       16380
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       66776620226 (31842 GB)
```

in result i got: 31842 GB/16380 hours = **1.94 GB/hour** or **46.65 GB/day**.
i think it is very big numbers for my case. i don't have any software, which can write such amount of data every day.

i tried to run **iotop** in cumulative mode (TOP-10 sorted by **DISK WRITE** for ~2 days):

```
Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :    0.00 B/s
Actual DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:    0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ DISK WRITE>  SWAPIN      IO    COMMAND                                                                                                       
  191 be/3 root          0.00 B      3.90 G  0.00 %  7.92 % [jbd2/sda1-8]
 8648 be/4 kondrush     52.14 M      3.00 G  0.00 %  0.14 % mysql-workbench-bin
 1308 be/4 mysql         4.00 K   1159.27 M  0.00 %  0.00 % mysqld
 5077 be/4 kondrush     21.22 M    920.98 M  0.00 %  0.02 % chrome [LevelDBEnv.IDB]
 4715 be/4 kondrush      2.52 M    286.57 M  0.00 %  0.00 % chrome [Chrome_SyncThre]
 2119 be/4 kondrush    384.00 K    261.57 M  0.00 %  0.00 % gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
 1163 be/4 root          9.76 M    182.50 M  0.00 %  0.00 % python /usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
 4421 be/4 kondrush     36.00 M     99.48 M  0.00 %  0.00 % chrome [Chrome_HistoryT]
26121 be/4 kondrush    180.00 K     94.10 M  0.00 %  0.03 % chrome [TaskSchedulerFo]
 8779 be/4 kondrush     17.47 M     67.33 M  0.00 %  0.00 %
```

so using **iotop**-data it was written about 10GB+. but comparing "Total LBAs Written"-column from **smartctl** for this 2 days i see that it was written ~51GB.

**main question:**

how i can identify which software writes so much LBA and why **smartctl**-counts are different of **iotop**-counts

Answer (score 1):

answering on my question. i found the writer.
It was MySQL Workbench.

how i found it:

1. used `System Monitor` to see which process makes biggest write operations (column `Disk write total`)
2. used `ptrace` to trace process of `MySQL Workbench` to try to understand what it does

i noted that **EACH 9-10 SECONDS** it writes portion of some data. and then i understood that it is Auto-Save functionality and it is bug in it.

FYI. i have a lot of tabs opened in Workbench, and it saved ALL OPENED TABS **without analyze was it edited after last auto-save or not**. in result i described bug https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=95855 and it was approved, but since 3 years i don't see was it resolved or not.

P.S. i hope this information will be helpful for someone